# How to check whether user has seen the push notification permissions alert view before in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, push-notification

I wanted to show a message to users at the start of the app just before showing the push notification permissions alert view. In order to determine whether I should display the message, I need to know whether user has seen the push notification permissions alert view before.

Answer (score 3):

You can use NSUserDefaults.

After you call regusterNotifications: which shows the permissions.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasShown"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To check if it has shown, assuming that means the Boolean value for hasShown is Yes.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasShown"])
    // user has seen before
```

Note that this only checks if the permissions request has been sent before. This does not validate whether your push notifications is still activated for the given app.

Comment: The problem with this is if you're doing it as an update to an already existing app, it won't be accurate.

Comment: @Marty - Idea: for the key, instead of `@"hasShown"` you can do like: `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"shownIn-%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]`